# How to set table storage as output in azure function app v2?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have created function app at azure portal using javascript, here is code from `index.js` file

```
module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {

context.log('IotMessage ' + JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage));
var date = Date.now();
var partitionKey = Math.floor(date / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + '';
var rowKey = date + '';

context.bindings.ParamMessageLog = {
    "partitionKey": partitionKey,
    "rowKey": rowKey,
    "MsgCount": iotHubMessage.length,
    "data": JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage)
};


context.done();
};
```

I have also manually installed storage package as per instructions given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/install-update-binding-extensions-manual)

snippet from `function.json` file

```
{
  "type": "table",
  "name": "ParamMessageLog",
  "tableName": "MessageLog",
  "connection": "<storage account name>_STORAGE",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

content of `extensions.csproj` file is as below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The issue is when I restarted my app I am seeing following error and can not run/test function.

```
Error:
Function (PBDataGateway) Error: The binding type(s) 'eventHubTrigger, table' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

please advice where I need to change. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may have missed this package which is used to generate extensions metadata.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.*" />
```

After add this line, repeat the installation steps in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/install-update-binding-extensions-manual#install-a-binding-extension).